# Nmap http-title.nse - Host Header

Tags: security, scripting, nmap

I'm trying to scan a number of IPs using the script: http-title.nse
Unfortunately I don't want it to use the IP as a Host-Header but a custom value.

Currently the requests look something like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nmap Scripting Engine; https://nmap.org/book/nse.html)
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: close
```

But I would like to have the Host Header field overwritten by a --script-args field like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Nmap Scripting Engine; https://nmap.org/book/nse.html)
Host: example.host.com
Connection: close
```

Can someone help me to either modify the script itself or if it's already possible give me a hint on how to overwrite it?

Thanks a lot and keep on coding

Answer (score 0):

Nmap will use the following sources to find a name to put in the Host header:

1. The target name from the command line, like `nmap -p80 example.com`
2. The reverse-DNS name, if you did not use the `-n` option to suppress this feature.
3. The IP address (as you found).

Someone (possibly you?) has submitted a pull request to add [a script like this to Nmap](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/pull/1251). I responded there with a request for more information, since it seems like just using the target name directly would do what you want. I suppose you may want to override it if the name does not actually resolve to the IP address you want to scan. In that case, I would add an entry to `/etc/hosts` to force it to resolve correctly.

EDIT: I just added a new script-arg, `http.host`, to allow overriding the default Host header for most requests. It works for `http-title`.